# How to print outputs in same line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

```
f=open("quizq.txt","r+")
read=f.readlines()
f=open("quiza.txt","r+")
reada=f.readlines()
p=0
for p in range(len(read)):
    x=read[p]
    y=reada[p]
    p=p+1
    print(x,end=':')
    print(y)
```

output I want is `x:y`, Where `x` and `y` are the inputs by the user.

Comment: `print(f'{x}:{y}')`

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: @Yuvraj can you please mark the answer as accepted, your query is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your for with this:

```
for i in zip(read,reada): 
    print(i[0].strip(), ':', i[1].strip(), sep='')
```

or in your code:

```
print(x, ":", y, sep='')
```

Note that there is a problem in your code:

> The best practice for opening a file is to use `with`, because it will close the file automatically after. But if you dont want to use it, REMEBER to close the file, `f.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code snippet.

```
f=open("quizq.txt","r+")
read=f.readlines()
f=open("quiza.txt","r+")
reada=f.readlines()
p=0
for p in range(len(read)):
    x=read[p]
    y=reada[p]
    p=p+1
    print("{}:{}".format(str(x), str(y))
```